# Union with arel not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, arel

in our system, a user can have many orders, but only one will be active at a certain point in time. this active order has a field called `paid_premium_until`. if paid premium is set after now, he is premium, otherwise, the order expired and he is free. he will be free also if he has no order.

I want to select free users and I'm cant do this. Here is the code:

```
@users_table = BTR::User.arel_table
@users = users_table.select_manager
@users.join(orders_table).on(users_table[:id].eq(orders_table[:user_id]))
      .where(orders_table[:paid_premium_until].lt(Time.now).or(orders_table[:intermediate_premium_until].lt(Time.now)))
      .union(:all, BTR::User.joins(:orders).where('btr_order.user_id IS NULL'))
```

I also tried this:

```
users_without_orders = BTR::User.arel_table
free_users = users_without_orders.join(orders_table).on(users_table[:id].eq(orders_table[:user_id]))
                                 .where(orders_table[:user_id].eq(nil))
```

and `.union(:all, free_users)` but I got the same error as above:

`undefined method where' for #<Arel::Nodes::UnionAll:0x007f8c0a4e1e50> (NoMethodError)`.

Comment: tried writing `where` clause first?

Comment: first where? what do you mean?

Comment: `users_without_orders.where(....).join...`

Comment: I get the same error